# deep compare arrays in yui

Tags: yui

is there a recommended way to deep compare 2 arrays in yui3 tests (similar to QUnit's deepEqual)? I poked around the source and the best I could come up with was to steal this function from matrix/matrix.js (shown slightly rewritten) It could easily be modified to a recursive arbitrary depth comparison, but I'm digressing now...

```
function compare(list1, list2)
{
    var i = 0, len = list1.length, len2 = list2.length, isEqual = len === len2;
    if(isEqual) {
        for(; i < len; ++i) {
            if(list1[i] != list2[i]) {
                isEqual = false; break;
            }
        }
    }
    return isEqual;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, YUI Tests have an `Test.ArrayAssert` namespace where you have many assertions for arrays. In particular you have `itemsAreEqual` which tests with `==` and `itemsAreEquivalent` which uses `===`. You get this for free by including the `test` module.

```
YUI().use('test', function (Y) {
  var ArrayAssert = Y.Test.ArrayAssert;

  var testCase = new Y.Test.Case({
    name: "TestCase Name", 

    //traditional test names
    testSomething : function () {
      ArrayAssert.itemsAreEqual([1, 2, 3], foo, 'all items should be 1, 2, 3');
    }
  });
});
```